# Form submission without parameter name in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form with an input and a submit button. 
If the user types in 'plane' and clicks the button it would submit to *example.com/something?q=plane*. How can I make it go to *example.com/something/plane* ?

For now, I've only written it in HTML, but I think that I would need a rails helper to do that. (it has to be a "get" request)

```html
<form action="/something" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Help me">
  <button type="submit">Results</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you have to update the url of the form right after clicking submit and submit the form via js.
Or you do an API call in js.

Comment: Does it matter if the request is GET or POST? Usually a post request would achieve what you want in this situation

Comment: @ThorTL67 It has to be a get request ..

Answer (score 0):

Use post method in form.

```
<form method="post"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).on("submit", "form[data-turboform]", function(e) {
    var query = $(this).serialize().substring($(this).serialize().indexOf('q=') + 2);
    Turbolinks.visit(this.action + '/' + query);
    return false;
  });
```

This jQuery code  will trigger on form submit and generate link then using `Turbolinks.visit` go to the route. Keep in mind this is only for GET requests

```
<%= form_tag orders_path, method: :get, local: true, enforce_utf8: false, 'data-turboform': true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Help Me'  %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit'%>
<% end %>
```